# ways to load page faster

Tags: php, mysql, database, performance, loading

I am making a bolg website using php, mysql. it features photo uploads, poll, event, user comment, private messaging, add fren, news etc. all most all my obstacles are solved by stackoverflow (i am very thankful). this is my 2nd question and here it is:

what is the best way to fetch required information from database? i'v several options in my mind and which i am capable of doing :-)

1. store information as a JSON array then parse it with jQuery,
2. store info as array and parse it at required region with php,
3. following conventional method - mysql query wherever required.

which method will be faster or if there is any others method you can suggest me will be helpful.

Comment: I'd think #2 is most likely to be the fastest, provided your server is reasonably fast, and assuming you mean creating dom elements on the fly with #1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely #3.  Storing the data in a way the database can understand allows for more flexibility and makes it easier to use.  By storing the data serialized, you can't do anything with it in the database.  If, for example, you wanted just the title and author of all post, with method 3, you could get just those fields.  Method 1 or 2 would require you to pull out all of the data, parse it into PHP, and then select only what you want from it.  You also couldn't do things like sorting or getting posts for a specific user.  You wouldn't gain anything from serializing the data before putting it in the database.  The data would be roughly the same size and any difference in retrieval speed would be negligible.

Comment: Thanks G-Nugget, ya no. 3 does makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Out of the three that you have listed, you never really listed how the data will persist in numbers 1 and 2. Unless of course you are thinking of dumping array and JSON data into a text file... which is honestly out of the question if speed is your concern.

If you want data to persist while keeping the structure, you might want to take a look at other solutions, such as MongoDB and PostgreSQL. They're very good options as far as performance goes as well. But if you're already using MySQL there really isn't much reason to make that sort of transition unless you have a very compelling reason to.

Comment: yes dumping array or json txt. PostgreSQL is new to me and i know nothing about it. though i already created tables in mysql but if i need to change my db then this is the right time. so let me do some research about it. at the mean time if you can provide some good points PostgreSQL over mysql keeping in mind what i intend to do will throw some light on my project. once again thanks for your time.